# DataGridTextColumn getting DataContext property

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

Hi in a DataGridTextColumn I am binding to a new DataContext which works

```
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" 
           Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.CollectionName}"  Width="150">
```

However, the TextBox says "(Collection)" so is there a way to display a properly within the Collection?

In a DataGridComboBox you state:

```
<Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="PropertyName"/>
```

But you dont have this property in a DataGridTextColumn.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.CollectionName.PropertyName}"
```

should bind to the given `PropertyName`

Comment: I thought that too (I agree the logic is right, but it never worked)

Comment: Well, I also think that your whole binding is not necessary at all. Is there any reason for this? What are you trying to archive?

Comment: I have done it now, but, I have 2 combo boxes that the itemsource is different to the itemsource of the DataGrid. So whenever a user selects a ID in the combobox, I wanted the name of this ID to appear in the DataGridTextColumn, but the problem is, the DataGridTextColumn is binded to the DataContext of the DataGrid so I couldn't achieve this. The DataContext has to be the one of the combo box

Comment: Where is the problem? If you bound a `ObservableCollection` to your DataGrid, you could simply add a new entry and the DataGrid changes (assuming you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly)